# TS2339: Property 'batch' does not exist on type 'BatchDashboardComponent'

Tags: angular, typescript, primeng

So I'm trying to display some mock data on a table in this pug file

```
  .container
    p-table([value]="batches")
      ng-template(pTemplate="header")
        tr
          th Batch ID
          th Batch Start
          th Batch End
          th Mismatched Customers
          th Customers Evaluated
      ng-template(pTemplate="body" let-batch='')
        tr
          td {{batch.batchId}}
          td {{batch.batchStart}}
          td {{batch.batchEnd}}
          td {{batch.quantityMismatched}}
          td {{batch.quantityEvaluated}}
```

But I keep on getting errors that say that the property 'batch' doesn't exist on type 'BatchDashboardComponent'

Here is the typescript file I have

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { BatchData } from '../../util/data';
import { BATCHES } from '../../util/mock-data';
import { BatchService } from '../../services/batch/batch.service';

@Component({
  selector: 'batch-dashboard',
  templateUrl: './batch-dashboard.component.pug',
  styleUrls: ['./batch-dashboard.component.scss'],
  providers: [BatchService]
})
export class BatchDashboardComponent implements OnInit {
  batches: BatchData[];

  constructor(){

  }

  ngOnInit(){
    this.batches = BATCHES;
    console.log(this.batches);
  }
}
```

Where BATCHES is the mock data of type BatchData which looks like this

```
export interface BatchData {
  batchId: number,
  batchStart: string,
  batchEnd: string,
  quantityMismatched: number,
  quantityEvaluated: number
}
```

any idea as to why I'm getting this error would be appreciated?

EDIT:
i've also tried doing these to no avail

```
.centered-col-8
  .container
    p-table([value]="batches")
      ng-template(pTemplate="header")
        tr
          th Batch ID
          th Batch Start
          th Batch End
          th Mismatched Customers
          th Customers Evaluated
      ng-template(pTemplate="body" let-batch)
        tr
          td {{batch.batchId}}
          td {{batch.batchStart}}
          td {{batch.batchEnd}}
          td {{batch.quantityMismatched}}
          td {{batch.quantityEvaluated}}
```

```
.centered-col-8
  .container
    p-table([value]="batches")
      ng-template(pTemplate="header")
        tr
          th Batch ID
          th Batch Start
          th Batch End
          th Mismatched Customers
          th Customers Evaluated
      ng-template(pTemplate="body" let-batch [ngForOf]="batches")
        tr
          td {{batch.batchId}}
          td {{batch.batchStart}}
          td {{batch.batchEnd}}
          td {{batch.quantityMismatched}}
          td {{batch.quantityEvaluated}}
```

Comment: because you defined `let-batch=''`, seems like syntax issue. not much involved with pug

Comment: how would you suggest i fix this?

Comment: Agreed, the Pug isn't where the issue is occurring.

Comment: try using this `batches: BatchData[] = [];`, by doing so error should change.

Comment: I tried this and nothing changed, same errors as before

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think I solved the issue, I added this into the typescript file and the errors went away

```
batch: BatchData;
```